# How to properly wait for props in child component from parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-props

I have created a child component which iterates to a variable that was sent from the parent component. The parent components sends an axios request to the backend and then sends it down to the child component. Sometimes it does work but sometimes it renders before the prop gets to the child component and it triggers an undefined error for the loop.

Parent Component

```
  <div class="permissions">
    <p class="sub-heading-2">Permission Selection</p>
      <PermissionSelection 
        v-if="permissions"
        @permissionsData="log" 
        v-for="category in categories" 
        :key="category.id"
        :category="category" 
        :companies="companies" 
        :userPermission="permissions"
        :errors="errors"
        :company_errors="company_assignment_error"
    />
  </div>
```

Child Component

```
 onBeforeMount(() => {
   watch(props, () => {
     props.userPermission.permission.forEach(permission => {
        if(props.category.category == permission.permission[0].name) {
          isCollapsed.value = true
          subcategory.value = true

          if(permission.is_reporting_to == true && permission.is_attribute == false && propsLoadCount.value == 1) {
            assign.value = 'reporting'
          } else if (permission.is_reporting_to == false && permission.is_attribute == true) {
              assign.value = 'company'

              if(!company_errors_arr.value.includes(permission.permission[0].name) && propsLoadCount.value == 1) {
                companiesAssigned.value = []

                permission.attributes.forEach(attribute => {
                   companiesAssigned.value.push(attribute.attributable_id)
                })
              }

              if(errors_arr.value.includes(permission.permission[0].name)) {
                 assign.value = ''
              }
                            
              if(companiesAssigned.value.length === props.companies.length) {
                 isAllChecked.value = 'true'
              }
          }
        }
     })
   }, {deep: true})
 })
```

I have already tried putting the function inside onBeforeMount but it does not fix the problem. The only method that I had successfully made it work is by using a setTimeout function before proceeding with the loop, this works but I don't think it would be a permanent solution. Just need some help with making the child component wait until the prop is there before actually running the code for the loop.

Comment: you don't need wait data in child component, vue is reactive and updates child component on props changed, u need pass props correctly. sry, u r question is not more informly to show u where u may have error (may be u need to await data from ur request function).

Comment: `watch` function should exist as top-level function, not inside `onBeforeMount` or anywhere else.  Also, your watcher will run regardless of which prop actually updates because you're watching the entire `props` object.  You can watch just the `userPermission` property with a [watcher getter function](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers). Finally, your v-if will render the Child as long as `permissions` is not undefined. Maybe you mean to check if it has non-empty child array, I think `permissions?.permission.length > 0` instead.